# keyword error on plotting the station data

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, group-by

I want to make a data availability plot using the following data sets so that graph should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arMOI.png) plot.

My data is

```
      Date      Stn1      Stn2      Stn3
1980-01-01       NaN  2.269755 -1.613898
1980-01-02  0.400157       NaN -0.212740
1980-01-03  0.978738  0.045759 -0.895467
1980-01-04       NaN -0.187184       NaN
1980-01-05       NaN  1.532779 -0.510805
1980-01-06 -0.977278  1.469359 -1.180632
1980-01-07  0.950088  0.154947 -0.028182
1980-01-08 -0.151357  0.378163       NaN
1980-01-09 -0.103219 -0.887786       NaN
1980-01-10  0.410599       NaN       NaN
1980-01-11  0.144044 -0.347912 -0.634322
1980-01-12       NaN  0.156349 -0.362741
1980-01-13  0.761038  1.230291 -0.672460
1980-01-14  0.121675  1.202380 -0.359553
1980-01-15  0.443863 -0.387327 -0.813146
1980-01-16  0.333674 -0.302303 -1.726283
1980-01-17       NaN       NaN       NaN
1980-01-18 -0.205158       NaN -0.401781
1980-01-19  0.313068       NaN -1.630198
1980-01-20 -0.854096  1.950775       NaN
1980-01-21 -2.552990 -0.509652 -0.907298
1980-01-22  0.653619 -0.438074       NaN
1980-01-23  0.864436       NaN       NaN
1980-01-24 -0.742165  0.777490       NaN
```

I tried below example code to plot the above

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import datetime
from matplotlib import dates as mdates

n = 3 # number of stations
stns = ['']
for i in range(n):
    stn = 'Stn' + str(i+1)
    stns.append(stn)
    df.loc[~np.isnan(df[stn]), stn] = i+1
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
dates = df.Date
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
ax = df.plot(legend=False)
ax.set_yticks(range(n+1))
ax.set_yticklabels(stns)
ax.set_xticks(range(len(dates)))
ax.set_xticklabels(dates, rotation=45, ha='right')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

But here error is: keyword error Date

I hope experts may help me overcoming this error.Thanks.

Comment: Why do the values in your dataframe en up flat in the plot you share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about simply using `pd.to_datetime()` and removing setting the index.

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import datetime
from matplotlib import dates as mdates
import pandas as pd 


df = pd.read_csv('retin.csv', header = 0,delimiter=r"\s+")
df.set_index('Date').plot();

n = 3 # number of stations

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

stns = ['']
for i in range(n):
    stn = 'Stn' + str(i+1)
    stns.append(stn)
    df.loc[~np.isnan(df[stn]), stn] = i+1
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
dates = df.Date
ax = df.plot(legend=False)
ax.set_yticks(range(n+1))
ax.set_yticklabels(stns)
ax.set_xticks(range(len(dates)))
ax.set_xticklabels(dates, rotation=45, ha='right')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

which gives:
[image]

Comment: Thanks @ Serge , can u please solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74797296/how-to-plot-data-availability-graph